# How do we find total number of odd multiples of a number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example: Find odd multiples of 7 less than 500. [only +ve values]

I know that to find the multiples of 7 b/w 1 and 499, we find the smallest and largest multiple of 7 within the given range. So here that would be 7 and  497. We subtract the quotient of the larger no. by the smaller no. and add 1.

7×1=7

7×71=497

which is, 71 - 1 + 1 = 71

so, there are 71 numbers b/w 1 and 499 that are multiples of 7.
But now how to find how many of these 71 are odd?

Comment: How many multiples of $14$ are less than $500$?

Answer (score 0):

$a \times 7$ is even if and only if $2|a$ (Gauss' theorem). So, roughly half of your numbers are odd, and half are even (I let you handle the + or - $1$).

Answer (score 0):

All odd multiples of $7$ can be found by taking multiples of $14$ and subtracting $7$ from each of them. So your problem is reduced to finding the number of multiples of $14$ less than $507$. This can be done by taking the integer part of $\frac{506}{14},$ which is $36.$

Thus, there are $36$ odd multiples of $7$ less than $500$.